# json "invalid label" - when parsing google Distance Matrix Request

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, jquery

I'm having hard time with this simple ajax call

```
function sendreq()
{
    $.ajax({
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        url: 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Seattle&destinations=San+Francisco&mode=driving&sensor=false',
        success: function (jsonp)
        {
            alert('success');
        }                
    });
}
```

I'm able to see the api result in json format when i hit the url from browser and seems like jQuery sees the result too but is unable to parse.
it throws an error

> invalid label "destination_addresses" : [ "San Francisco, CA, USA" ],

im using jQuery 1.7.1. from ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js
any help would be appreciated
thanks.

Comment: Well, JSON is not JSONP, yet you tell jQuery to treat the response as JSONP. If the API does not support JSONP, then you are out of luck (and have to use a proxy instead).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need to use the JavaScript API?
http://www.quora.com/Why-doesnt-the-Google-Maps-API-support-JSONP, 
http://blog.futtta.be/2010/04/09/no-more-jsonp-for-google-geocoding-webservice

Comment: thanks for the links, I was wondering if I'm doing something wrong or its just the API? if nobody comes up with solution i guess i'll use javascript api

Comment: Why would you want to use the web service in this way anyway? Why not use the direct JavaScript API?

Answer (score 1):

You can't get `Distance Matrix`'s data by `Ajax`, because of [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). If you are using [Google Distance Matrix API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/) , the only way you can retrieve that data, is from your server-side script. The other method is, you can use [Distance Matrix Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix#usage_limits_and_requirements). For both methods(API and Service) you have to notice `Usage Limits and Requirements`:

> Use of the Distance Matrix service must relate to the display of
>   information on a Google Map; for example, to determine
>   origin-destination pairs that fall within a specific driving time from
>   one another, before requesting and displaying those destinations on a
>   map. Use of the service in an application that doesn't display a
>   Google map is prohibited.